# how do i tell zig to output an IR file when building my program

Tags: zig

How do i tell zig (either at the command-line or in my `build.zig` file to create/generate/save an IR file corresponding to my program?

Right now, I'm able to "disassemble" the `.elf` file -- but would like something a little higher-level.

Comment: did you try the `--verbose-llvm-ir` option? see [build-system](https://ziglang.org/learn/build-system/)

Comment: @FObersteiner that could be part of an Answer if it's so simple!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following inside your build script-

```js
const exe = b.addExecutable(.{
    ...
});

const ir_file = b.addInstallFile(exe.getEmittedLlvmIr(), "my_exe.ll");
b.getInstallStep().dependOn(&ir_file.step);
```

After running `zig build`, the generated LLVM IR in `zig-out/my_exe.ll`

If you want to get the assembly file, just replace `exe.getEmittedLlvmIr()` with `exe.getEmittedAsm()`!